# search bar and display controller - tableView problems

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to add a search bar and display controller into my iOS project using storyboards.

The tutorials I have followed are on 'Appcoda' and 'Ray Wenderlich'. However, in my project I have custom `UITableViewCells` that expand their height when a small arrow at the bottom of the cell is pressed (using `heightForRowAtIndexPath`). But when I type in the search bar, I am aware that the same `tableview` (the original one with the custom cells and heights) is used to populate the search display controller's `tableView`.

How to use a basic `tableView` for search results instead, with just a title, image and subtitle on each cell, as apposed to my custom one?

Comment: search bar and display controller make more problem in tableview , use only search bar , it will fine does not create problem, u need sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only has one tableview and that tableview is being reloaded after your search, then obviously the same tableview will be used.

What you need (if I understand your question correctly) is to have 2 custom cell. You can identify them via different cellidentifier on storyboard. And use them based on different occasions.